# How to navigate from /documentation/review to the current revision of what I'm reviewing

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, review-queues

I want to navigate from [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/92539) to its topic... I can't figure out how I could?

Comment: If someone could suspend all the reviewers and delete the approved example, that would be great.

Comment: "If someone could suspend all the reviewers and delete the approved example" How about sometwo? An ordinary user (e.g me) can [delete the example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94321) and a mod can suspend the reviewers.

Comment: Maybe it could be a `[feature-request]`?

Comment: All the times I've tried this morning, clicking the topic name took me to the topic. But not on the one you've linked. That might be (most probably is) because it was just created with that edit, so the link did not exist when the review task was created.

Comment: As to that example, though at least one of them is a robo-reviewer from the look of it, I think most people are approaching this the same as they do the standard review queues and do not understand the need to run a cursory search to check that edits are not plagiarized. Due to the major problem this has proven to be on SOD and the fact that reviewing documentation should be different than Q&A (would seem obvious considering the different focuses but I've seen at least one comment that showed a lack of this understanding)

Comment: @Braiam I honestly think I will not review documentation changes from tomorrow because personally to me it seems I approve around 75% of suggestions while the remaining are skipped. I think reviewing documentation is not my thing.